# Deploying a simple Play application to CloudFoundry just "GAVE UP"

Tags: playframework, cloud-foundry

I'm following the [instructions on the CloudFoundry blog](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/play/java-getting-started.html) to deploy a simple Play application. I picked the "Create a simple Java application" option:

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro:tmp simonmacdonald$ play new helloworld-java
       _            _ 
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/ 

play! 2.0.4, http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in /Users/simonmacdonald/Work/tmp/helloworld-java

What is the application name? 
> helloworld-java

Which template do you want to use for this new application? 

  1 - Create a simple Scala application
  2 - Create a simple Java application
  3 - Create an empty project

> 2

OK, application helloworld-java is created.

Have fun!
```

Then I'm able to verify the app works properly on the local machine. Next step is to build the distribution:

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro:helloworld-java simonmacdonald$ play dist
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/simonmacdonald/Work/tmp/helloworld-java/project
[info] Set current project to helloworld-java (in build file:/Users/simonmacdonald/Work/tmp/helloworld-java/)
[info] Packaging /Users/simonmacdonald/Work/tmp/helloworld-java/target/scala-2.9.1/helloworld-java_2.9.1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.

Your application is ready in /Users/simonmacdonald/Work/tmp/helloworld-java/dist/helloworld-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip

[success] Total time: 2 s, completed 1-Feb-2013 4:35:48 PM
```

Which looks like it succeeds. Then I do my target and login using:

```
vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com
vmc login
```

Next up I push the app up to the server:

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro:helloworld-java simonmacdonald$ vmc push --path=dist/helloworld-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip 
Name> helloworld-java

Instances> 1

1: play
2: other
Framework> 1   

1: java
2: java7
3: other
Runtime> 1

1: 64M
2: 128M
3: 256M
4: 512M
Memory Limit> 256M

Creating helloworld-java... OK

1: helloworld-java.cloudfoundry.com
2: none
URL> helloworld-java.cloudfoundry.com

Updating helloworld-java... OK

Create services for application?> n

Bind other services to application?> n

Save configuration?> y

Saving to manifest.yml... OK
Uploading helloworld-java... OK
Using manifest file manifest.yml

Starting helloworld-java... OK
Checking helloworld-java... GAVE UP
Application failed to start.
```

As you can see the app fails to start. When I check the status it is at 0% and trying to retrieve the logs causes a crash of vmc. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This may have been a temporary vmc problem. Have you tried uninstalling vmc and reinstalling --pre? Then trying the process again?